# Arrow keys ignore selection via Gtk.FlowBox.select_child()

Tags: python, gtk3

When I use Gtk.FlowBox.select_child() programmatically the selection works fine. But if I use arrow keys to move the selection afterwards, it ignores the previously selected item and moves from the first item in the FlowBox. I don't know if this is a bug or I have to do something else to make the cursor know the new location. Selecting with mouse works as expected.

I'm using gtk3 version 3.24.23 on Linux.

```
import os
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf

# just a folder with a bunch of png images. 
ICON_DIR = os.path.expanduser("~/.icons")

class Window(Gtk.Window):
    
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.set_default_size(480, 400)
        self.scr_win = Gtk.ScrolledWindow(parent=self)
        self.flowbox = Gtk.FlowBox(parent=self.scr_win, homogeneous=True, 
                row_spacing=8, column_spacing=8, min_children_per_line=4, 
                max_children_per_line=100)
        
        for i, icon_name in enumerate(os.listdir(ICON_DIR)):
            self.flowbox.insert(
                    Gtk.Image.new_from_pixbuf( 
                    GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_size(
                    os.path.join(ICON_DIR, icon_name), 64, 64)), i)
        
        self.show_all()

        # selecting the 51st item just as an example:
        selected = self.flowbox.get_child_at_index(50)
        self.flowbox.select_child(selected)
        self.scr_win.get_vadjustment().set_value(selected.get_allocation().y)
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    win = Window()
    win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
    Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was grab focus after the selection:

```
selected.grab_focus()
```